# Print decision trees in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a project on the university of making a decision tree, i already have the code that creates the tree but i want to print it, can anyone help me?

```
#IMPORT ALL NECESSARY LIBRARIES
import Chefboost as chef
import pandas as pd

archivo = input("INSERT FILE NAMED FOLLOWED BY .CSV:\n")
# READ THE DATA SET FROM THE CSV FILE
df = pd.read_csv(str(archivo))
df.columns = ['ph', 'soil_temperature', 'soil_moisture', 'illuminance', 'env_temperature','env_humidity','Decision']
# print(df.head(10)) #UNCOMMENT IF WANT FIRST 10 ROWS PRINTED OUT


config = {'algorithm':'ID3'} # CONFIGURE THE ALGORITH. CHOOSE BETWEEN ID3, C4.5, CART, Regression
model = chef.fit(df.copy(), config) #CREATE THE DECISION TREE BASED OF THE CONFIGURATION ABOVE

resultados = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Real", "Predicción"]) #CREATE AN EMPTY PANDAS DATAFRAME
# SAVE ALL REAL VS ESTIMATED VALUES IN THE ABOVE DATAFRAME
for i in range(1,372):
    l = []
    l.append(df.iloc[i]['Decision'])
    feature = df.iloc[i]
    prediction = chef.predict(model, feature)
    l.append(prediction)
    resultados.loc[i] = l
    print(l)
```

Comment: Have a look at [this medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-a-decision-tree-from-a-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-38ad2d75f21c).

Comment: Do you have to use `chef`, or can you use `sklearn`?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the Chefboost library, I can't directly answer your question, but when I am working with a new library, I will often use a few tools to help me understand what the library is giving me.  Use dir(object) to get a listing of the attributes and methods of the object.

You might also get a little more specific about what you want to see when you "Print the decision tree."  Are you trying to print the model, or the predictions?  What trouble are you having or what errors are you seeing?

Hope this helps.